# WPF - Why doesn't Visual Studio find my Style in separate ResourceDictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, data-binding

I created and added the following ResourceDictionary within my App.Resources

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GanttTesting.Views"
                xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<sys:Double x:Key="CommandCenterExpandedTagRatio">1</sys:Double>
<sys:Double x:Key="CommandCenterCollapsedTagRatio">0</sys:Double>
<sys:String x:Key="CommandCenterCollapsedTagRatioAsString">0.1</sys:String>
<sys:Double x:Key="CommandCenterExpandedWidth">330</sys:Double>

<Style x:Key="CommandCenterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:CommandCenter}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

However, when using the "Create new Binding" window in Visual Studio and selecting "Static Resource", while "CommandCenterExpandedTagRatio" and the other String and Double values are displayed properly, "CommandCenterStyle" doesn't appear. Typing it manually doesn't work either.
Did I do something wrong here? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: How are you trying to apply the style resource, i.e. to what element/property?

Comment: I would like my style to be applied to any button I create, at least within a certain xaml file

Comment: The `Style` you have posted can only be applied to `CommandCenter` elements...

Answer (score 0):

Note reading [Styles and templates (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/styles-templates-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0) and [How to create a style for a control (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-apply-style?view=netdesktop-6.0#relationship-of-the-targettype-property-and-the-xkey-attribute).

`<Style x:Key="CommandCenterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:CommandCenter}">` in your styles.

This applies the style to the `CommandCenter`, it doesn't apply to the `button` control.

This tutorial can teach you how to create a [style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-apply-template?view=netdesktop-6.0).